# I want to generate cards and give them values but I get an infinite loop. How do I solve this?

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Dim checks(10) As Integer
Dim pick() As Short

Dim random As New Random

Dim counter As Short = 0

Private Sub Game_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cards() As PictureBox = {C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, C16, C17, C18, C19, C20}

    For i = 1 To 20
        CardProperties(cards(counter))
        counter += 1
    Next
End Sub

Public Function CardProperties(x As PictureBox) As PictureBox
    Do
        Dim a As Short = random.Next(1, 10)

        If checks(a) < 2 Then
            x.Tag = a
            checks(a) += 1
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    Return x
End Function
```

How do I not get an infinite loop when checking if a has already been selected twice? Also this is a memory game, where you select card couples.

I have tried changing the if checks(a) < 3 and it did work, though it created incomplete couples and it wasn't what I needed.

Comment: Do you really want to do a shuffle from a fixed deck instead of a completely random generation?  I would consider that to be more typical for a card game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no `checks(a)` are less than 2 then the loop will never finish.

Note that in [Random.Next(Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-8.0#system-random-next(system-int32-system-int32)) the second parameter is the exclusive upper bound. So, you might have to call this instead in order to include 10:

```vb
Dim a As Integer = random.Next(1, 11)
```

Otherwise you will attempt to increment only 9 elements 20 times. I.e., after 18 times they will all have a value of 2.

Note that it returns an `Integer` and array indexes are also expected to be of type `Integer`.

There are [good reasons](https://devtut.github.io/vbnet/option-strict.html) to set `Option Strict On` in VB.

--

Array indexes range from 0 to array length - 1. You are not using element (0). This is okay, but don't forget this if you get an array by calling a .NET function. They are all meant to be used by starting at index 0. Example:

```vb
Dim s As String = "You get it"
Dim words As String() = s.Split()
For i As Integer = 0 To words.Length - 1
    Console.WriteLine(words(i))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd explicitly put the numbers 1 to 10 in a List, TWICE, then shuffle it. Afterwards you can assign the numbers to the `.Tag` of the PictureBoxes:

```
Dim cards() As PictureBox = {
    C1, C2, C3, C4, C5,
    C6, C7, C8, C9, C10,
    C11, C12, C13, C14, C15,
    C16, C17, C18, C19, C20
}

Dim R As New Random
Dim nums As New List(Of Integer)
nums.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
nums.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
nums = nums.OrderBy(Function(x) R.Next()).ToList()

For i As Integer = 1 To 20
    cards(i - 1).Tag = nums(i - 1)
Next
```

Comment: Depending on the contract for OrderBy, it may not be strictly correct to use a random function for describing the ordering (though the implications of violating the contract may not have an effect for a shuffle).